# Java NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java

I am trying to understand stacks with Objects, so I typed this out, but the problem is that I am getting this really weird message that I can't make sense of.  It says "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Stack.push(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at TestObjectStack.main(TestObjectStack.java:12)".  I googled it, but I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I redid the main method header, but that  didn't fix it.  Does anyone have any suggestions or insight that I am missing?  Thanks a lot!:

```
public class TestObjectStack 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Object o;
    Stack test = new Stack();

    test.push("Fred");
    test.push(20);
    test.push(new ThingB("Barney", 42));

    Stack copy = new Stack(test);

    System.out.println("Stack test: " + test);
    System.out.println(test.pop());
    System.out.println("Stack test: " + test);
    System.out.println("Stack copy: " + copy);
    if(test.isEmpty()) System.out.println("Empty");

    o = test.pop();
    System.out.println(o);
    if(o instanceof String)
    {
        String s = (String) o;
        System.out.println("String length = " + s.length());
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Not a String");
    if(test.isEmpty()) System.out.println("Empty");

    o = test.pop();
    System.out.println(o);
    if(o instanceof String)
    {
        String s = (String) o;
        System.out.println("String length = " + s.length());
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Not a string");
    if(test.isEmpty()) System.out.println("empty");
}
 }

class ThingB
{
private String _name;
private int _ID;

public ThingB(String name, int ID)
{
    _name = name;
    _ID = ID;
}

public String toString()
{
    return "Thing B - name - " + _name + " ID = " + _ID;
}
}

class Stack
{
private Object[] _store;
private int _top;
private static final int MAXSIZE = 50;

public Stack()
{
    _store = new Object[MAXSIZE];
    _top = 0;
}

public Stack(Stack other)
{
    _store = new Object[other._store.length];
    _top = other._top;
    for(int i = 0; i < _top; ++i)
    {
        _store[i] = other._store[i];
    }
}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return (_top == 0);
}

public void push(Object item)
{
    if(_top >= _store.length)
    {
        Object[] temp = new Object[_store.length+ MAXSIZE];
        for(int i = 0; i < _top; ++i)
        {
            temp[i] = _store[i];
        }
        _store = temp;
    }
    _store[_top] = item;
    ++_top;
}

public Object pop()
{
    if(_top == 0) return 0;
    --_top;
    return  _store[_top];
}

public String toString()
{
    String s = "";

    s = s + "--Top--";
    for(int i = _top-1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        s = s + " " + _store[i];
    }
    s = s + "--Bottom--";

    return s;
}

}
```

Comment: Recompile everything.

Comment: I tried that.  Copied everything, deleted the program, and repasted it all after creating another, yet the problem persists.

Comment: Make sure you don't have your code opened in *multiple text editors*. Verify the source file path, if compiling via cmd. If you are using IDE e.g. try *Clean and Build* before running code.

Comment: You tried it but you didn't succeed at it. The message basically means you aren't running the code you think you're running.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  It seems it was a problem with my IDE.  I transferred the code to another computer and it worked fine.  I'll need to figure this out later.  Thanks a lot, though, for the help.

Answer (score -1):

I executed your code in the IDE: IntelliJ IDEA. And I have the following result:

```
Stack test: --Top-- Thing B - name - Barney ID = 42 20 Fred--Bottom--
Thing B - name - Barney ID = 42
Stack test: --Top-- 20 Fred--Bottom--
Stack copy: --Top-- Thing B - name - Barney ID = 42 20 Fred--Bottom--
20
Not a String
Fred
String length = 4
empty
```

Your source code is working fine, maybe you need to adjust your IDE parameters. Try with a simple "Hello World" program.

Best regards,

Alvaro

Comment: I tried that,  but unfortunately that didn't fix it.  The parameters part does seem as if it is probably true because I transferred my work from my laptop to my desktop and it seems to be working fine here.  I'll probably mess around with my IDE and see if I can fix it.  Thanks a lot for the input though.